# Dell XPS 13 9300 rebooted to Dell Recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, dell

I recently purchased this laptop with Ubuntu 20 pre-installed. It was working fine.

Yesterday I rebooted it: Instead of rebooting normally, it went to a grub prompt. I typed "exit" and wound up in "Dell Recovery" mode. I tried rebooting several times and checked bios settings, but couldn't boot to the normal partition... Finally I thought "ok I'll let Dell Recovery do its thing"... I saw the Ubuntu setup and it was copying files (it did not prompt me about anything until it was finished). After it was done, my computer was 100% wiped out with a fresh Ubuntu install. There was not even a warning or prompt about formatting the hard drive! What happened?

I talked to Dell support but they are not interested in helping me because they claim that it's an Ubuntu problem. This seems unlikely as I've never seen anything remotely similar in the past, but that's why I'm here.

Any ideas what could have caused this scenario?

Comment: if it is very recent maybe return it to Dell for them to fix?

Comment: 1) After recovery there is no sign of any system problem... 2) They claim that it was a software issue, and to be fair, SSD failures are pretty rare. I really just want to make sure that it doesn't happen again.

Comment: The only way to be sure that it won't happen again is to have a good backup of your system, that is of all the stuff that you cannot lose.  As for what happened, that will be impossible to tell now with the system being restored.  It could have been a grub, kernel, library, accidental deletion, update gone crazy, etc.  We just simply will not be able to tell.

Comment: Thanks for the response... My question & concern isn't about backups (I have backups). I've just never experienced anything remotely similar on an Ubuntu machine. How could the Dell Recovery format the hard drive without even asking me? I guess this is more a complaint about garbage Dell software... In which case I admit it's not an Ubuntu question (though Dell insists that it is).